# how to perform multiplication of a triadiagonal matrix with a tensor of different rank and outer dimensions in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The code below (modified tensorflow example) produces the error "All input tensors must have the same rank.". Similar error is given by mult operations of tf.linalg.LinearOperatorTridiag. I need to multiply an input by a tridiagonal matrix in a Keras layer, and ranks of tensors are different due to additional batch dimensions in the input of the layer. Any known practical solution for this?

```
import tensorflow as tf

superdiag = tf.constant([-1, -1, 0], dtype=tf.float64)
maindiag = tf.constant([2, 2, 2], dtype=tf.float64)
subdiag = tf.constant([0, -1, -1], dtype=tf.float64)
diagonals = [superdiag, maindiag, subdiag]
rhs = tf.constant([[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]], dtype=tf.float64)
x = tf.linalg.tridiagonal_matmul(diagonals, rhs, diagonals_format='sequence')
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to expand the first dimension

```
superdiag = tf.constant([-1, -1, 0], dtype=tf.float64)
maindiag = tf.constant([2, 2, 2], dtype=tf.float64)
subdiag = tf.constant([0, -1, -1], dtype=tf.float64)
diagonals = [tf.expand_dims(superdiag,0), tf.expand_dims(maindiag,0), tf.expand_dims(subdiag,0)]
rhs = tf.constant([[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]], dtype=tf.float64)
x = tf.linalg.tridiagonal_matmul(diagonals, rhs, diagonals_format='sequence')
```

Comment: This solution is not practical. In a keras layer, matching the outer dimensions and rank of the tridiagmatrix with input's dimension and rank would result in a huge tridiagmatrix that would have to be changed with different batch sizes.

Comment: I only add a dimension and the code works... I suggest you report your custom layer or a simplified version of it in order to provide the better solution

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I found a solution. Simply represented tridiagonal matrix as a product of two block diagonal operators. For some reason this absurd restriction on ranks and dimensions is only for tridioganal matrices and operators. The tridiagonal operator in the current implementation is completely useless. I am thinking to report this as an issue at Tensorflow github.